# Wrapper DIV in 100% width website

Tags: css, html

Im creating a website where the header, footer, body are all 100% width of the page, but I need all the content to be centered of the page no matter the resolution. I've tried using a wrapper but then the header and stuff are only 100% width of the wrapper and not the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going out on a limb and guess that the background color/imagery is 100% wide, but you want the actual content to be centered (with a fixed width?). Here is sample code that uses an internal wrapper `div` on each item to keep internal content centered. I would recommend doing something totally different and possibly using repeating backgrounds on the `html` and `body` elements, but I don't know what your page looks like.

So.., the following will work, but will alarm HTML purists because of the extra markup :)

You can view a (super ugly) example of this method [on this sample page](http://jsbin.com/idicu3) I put together.

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper {
   width: 960px; /* fixed width */
   margin: 0 auto; /* center */
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="header">
   <div class="wrapper">
   <h1>My Title</h1>
   </div>
</div>
<div id="content">
   <div class="wrapper">
   <h2>Sub Title</h2>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed 
      do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris 
      nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
   </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
   <div class="wrapper">
   <p class="credits">Copyright 2009 by Your Company.com, LLC</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't do this with a div element unless it has a specified width.

for just text, you can use

```
<div style="text-align: center;">text content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work for you:

The CSS:

```
body {
background-color: #e1ddd9;
font-size: 12px;
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, SunSans-Regular, Sans-Serif;
color:#564b47;
margin: 20px 140px  20px 140px;
text-align: center;
}
#content {
width: 100%;
padding: 0px;
text-align: left;
background-color: #fff;
overflow: auto;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<body> 
<div id="content"> 
<p><b>center</b><br /><br /> 
This BOX ist centered and adjusts itself to the browser window.<br /> 
The height ajusts itself to the content.<br /> 
</div> 
</body>
```

This example was taken from this site, which I found a while ago and always refer to it for nice simple, clean css templates: 
http://www.mycelly.com/

Answer (score 0):

Have a play with this

```
body    {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative; 
}

#content    {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Then in the HTML

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="content">
    <!-- place all of your content inside of here  -->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Matt the `margin-left` and `margin-right` do nothing meaningful because the width is `100%`.